# How can I fix "The connection was not closed. The current status of the connection: connecting."

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity

I developed an application with entity framework. Sometimes I get the

> The connection was not closed. The current status of the connection: connecting

I did some research on the internet but I couldn't figure it out. I would be very grateful if you could help

HomeController:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //return View(CacheHelper.getIndexNotesFromCache()); //Yazıları son değiştirilme tarihine göre sırala ve view'e gönder
            return View(noteManager.ListQueryable().Include(x=>x.Owner).Include(x=>x.Comments).Include(x=>x.Category).Include(x=>x.Likes).Where(x => x.IsDraft == false && x.IsApproved == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedOn).Take(10).ToList());
        }
```

My Note Entity:

```
public class Note : MyEntitesBase
{       
    public string Tittle { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsDraft { get; set; }
    public int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual EvernoteUser Owner { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; } 

    public Note()
    {
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Likes = new List<Liked>();
    }

}
```

My Comment Entity:

```
public class Comment : MyEntitesBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool CommentStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
    public virtual EvernoteUser Owner { get; set; } 
}
```

My DatabaseContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext :DbContext 
{
   public DbSet<EvernoteUser> EvernoteUsers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Liked> Likes { get; set; }

   public DatabaseContext()
   {           
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext,Configuration>()); 
        Database.Initialize(force: false);

    }

}
```

Comment: My guess is that it's some point when your accessing information from the database. You must not be closing the connection.

Comment: For a start, you are serializing entities which means that for each of the 10 notes, the serializer is going to want to lazy load the Owner, Category, and all Comments and Likes. Usually though this would manifest with the DbContext being disposed, not in a connecting state. Either way, you might reconsider sending entities to the view as it will perform a lot better if you don't and likely would avoid issues like this.

Comment: @StevePy I did but problem still not fully resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb738582(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Manually opening connection does not solve the problem. It only opens connection earlier. Otherwise the connection is open on the first download of the recordset. The problem was solved by adding

Pooling=false;

Comment: I have reviewed the subject "Pooling = false". I added it to Webconfig but the problem is not solved